# biblatex: "et al." also when uniquename = false

Tags: biblatex

With the `biblatex` option `uniquename = true` (and `citetracker = true, maxcitenames = 1`), I can with the addition of the code `\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}}` abbreviate any multi-authored work to `Author et al.` after its first full citation, cf. the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, citetracker = true, maxcitenames = 1, uniquename = true]{biblatex}
\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}} % cite all authors of multi-authored works only once
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1963,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon and Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "She loves you",
    YEAR = "1963"}
@BOOK{lennon2004,
    AUTHOR = "Sean Lennon",
    TITLE = "My father was John Lennon",
    YEAR = "2004"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\noindent\cite{lennon1963}\\
\cite{lennon1963}\\
\cite{lennon2004}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But when changing `uniquename = true` to `uniquename = false`, this doesn't work:

[image]

Question: How can I retain the functionality of `\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}}` also with the `biblatex` option `uniquename = false`?

---

**EDIT**
Carlo's [answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202601/9077) works, but now I'm curious how one can constrain this so that the `Author 1, Author 2, and Author 3` abbreviation to `Author 1 et al.` only kicks in when there are three or more authors of a work. In the MWE below, `Lennon and McCartney 1963` should remain as such in its second citation, whereas `Lennon, McCartney, Harrison, and Starkey 1970` should abbreviate to `Lennon et al. 1970` in its second citation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, citetracker = true, maxcitenames = 99, mincitenames = 2, uniquename = false]{biblatex}
\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{\defcounter{maxnames}{1}}{}} % cite all authors of multi-authored works only once
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1963,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon and Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "She loves you",
    YEAR = "1963"}
@BOOK{lennon1970,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon and Paul McCartney and George Harrison and Richard Starkey",
    TITLE = "We're breaking up now",
    YEAR = "1970"}
@BOOK{lennon2004,
    AUTHOR = "Sean Lennon",
    TITLE = "My father was John Lennon",
    YEAR = "2004"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\noindent\cite{lennon1963}\\
\cite{lennon1963}\\
\cite{lennon1970}\\
\cite{lennon1970}\\
\cite{lennon2004}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT to EDIT**

Carlo's answer below works perfectly. I've simplified the code a bit, though, and tweaked it a bit so that at least I will understand it when looking at it later `:)`:

```
\AtEveryCitekey% for every citation
    {%
        \ifnumgreater{\value{labelname}}{2}% if there are >2 authors
            {%
                \ifciteseen% and if citation has been seen before
                    {\setcounter{maxnames}{1}}% then cite only one author
                    {\setcounter{maxnames}{\value{labelname}}}% otherwise cite all authors
            }
            {\setcounter{maxnames}{\value{labelname}}}% otherwise cite ≤2 authors
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Change the logic". `maxcitenames = 99` in the `biblatex` options and `\defcounter{maxnames}{1}` in the `True` of `ifciteseen`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, citetracker = true, maxcitenames = 99, uniquename = false]{biblatex}
\AtEveryCitekey{%
    \ifciteseen
    {\defcounter{maxnames}{1}}
    {}} % cite all authors of multi-authored works only once
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1963,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon and Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "She loves you",
    YEAR = "1963"}
@BOOK{lennon2004,
    AUTHOR = "Sean Lennon",
    TITLE = "My father was John Lennon",
    YEAR = "2004"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\noindent\cite{lennon1963}\\
\cite{lennon1963}\\
\cite{lennon2004}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

### EDIT Answer to the edit question.##

I found two ways and goint to post both.

**The first**

This is not the best form, initially I didn't find another. In this way it is not used `\AtEveryCitekey`. It is used `listtotal` that is a counter of total number in the list (`author`, `editors`... or `labelname`). The counter `listtotal` is only allowed in *list formatting directives and does not hold a meaningful value when used anywhere else*.

In the `\patchlabelnameformat` if the value of `listtotal` is greater that two and it is the first citation set the `liststop` (maximun number of item list to print) in the `\value{listtotal}`. If not is the first citation, the `listtop` is set to 1. On the other hand, if the value of `listtotal` is less that two the `listtop` is set at `\value{listtotal}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, citetracker = true,maxnames=2, minnames=2,uniquename=false]{biblatex}

\def\fgt{\setcounter{liststop}{\value{listtotal}}} %first and greater than two
\def\nfgt{\setcounter{liststop}{1}} %non first and greater than two

\def\flt{\setcounter{liststop}{\value{listtotal}}} %first and lower than two

\def\patchlabelnameformat{%
 \ifnumgreater{\value{listtotal}}{2}
    {\ifciteseen
       {\nfgt}
       {\fgt}}
    {\flt}}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
 \patchlabelnameformat
 \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1963,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon and Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "She loves you",
    YEAR = "1963"}
@BOOK{lennon1970,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon and Paul McCartney and George Harrison and Richard Starkey",
    TITLE = "We're breaking up now",
    YEAR = "1970"}
@BOOK{lennon2004,
    AUTHOR = "Sean Lennon",
    TITLE = "My father was John Lennon",
    YEAR = "2004"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\noindent\cite{lennon1963}\\
\cite{lennon1963}\\
\cite{lennon1970}\\
\cite{lennon1970}\\
\cite{lennon2004}
\end{document}
```

**The Second**

The best form. It is used `\AtEveryCitekey`. The logic is the same to the first way, but it is not possible used `listtotal` and `listtop` because `\AtEveryCitekey` is not list formatting directive. Then, in this way is used the counter `labelname` and is set the `maxnames`. It is necessary to use `uniquelist=false` in the `biblatex` options.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, citetracker = true,uniquename=false,uniquelist=false]{biblatex}

\AtEveryCitekey{\maxminformat} % cite all authors of

\def\fgt{\setcounter{maxnames}{\value{labelname}}} %first and greater than two
\def\nfgt{\setcounter{minnames}{1}\setcounter{maxnames}{1}} %non first and greater than two

\def\flt{\setcounter{maxnames}{\value{labelname}}} %first and lower than two

\def\maxminformat{%
 \ifnumgreater{\value{labelname}}{2}
    {\ifciteseen
       {\nfgt}
       {\fgt}}
    {\flt}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1963,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon and Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "She loves you",
    YEAR = "1963"}
@BOOK{lennon1970,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon and Paul McCartney and George Harrison and Richard Starkey",
    TITLE = "We're breaking up now",
    YEAR = "1970"}
@BOOK{lennon2004,
    AUTHOR = "Sean Lennon",
    TITLE = "My father was John Lennon",
    YEAR = "2004"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\noindent\cite{lennon1963}\\
\cite{lennon1963}\\
\cite{lennon1970}\\
\cite{lennon1970}\\
\cite{lennon2004}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works! If you're up for the challenge, see my edit! ``:)``

Comment: @Sverre see my edit.

Comment: That works. I notice, however, that your definition for ``\flt`` is identical to the definition of ``\fgt``, so there's no need for both. There's also no need to set ``\minnames`` to 1.

Comment: @sverre It is True. :). I had another with the name `\nflt` but equals to `\flt`. `minnames` is residue of several attempts before trying `uniquelist = false`